# 2,2,6,6-Tetramethylpiperidine - Brønsted Basicity

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I understand that this molecule can only act as a Brønsted base because it is sterically hindered by its multiple methyl groups.

[image]

However, isn't the proton bound up in solution? Doesn't that increase the effective size of the proton? How then exactly is a proton expected to reach the site of basicity if it's tied up with multiple water molecules? Or is the size of the hydrated proton still quite small? Or does the proton separate from the water molecules once the proton is sufficiently close to the site of basicity (the lone pair on the nitrogen)?

Comment: I don't think there will be steric hinderence to a small cation proton

Comment: Right but we know for a fact the proton is solvated quite heavily in water, with many users on this very forum insisting that H3O+ is inadequate to describe the extent of solvation of the proton in water. So wouldn't this solvation bulk up the proton?

Comment: did you reseacrched its pKa, it is 11.07, stronger than methylamine, carbonate,phenoxide,ammonia,etc.

Comment: pKa of what? Hydronium ion? Also I don't see phenoxide ion as having a particularly high pKa in the first place.

Comment: see [here](http://www.zirchrom.com/organic.htm), you do no research on google?, it is stronger than unhindered amines.

Comment: I still remember you saying "The basicity of amines has to do not only with the degree of substitution with electron-releasing alkyl groups but also factors such as steric hindrance and degree of solvation." [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12322/field-effect-and-its-effect-on-basicity-on-amines/), see my answer you'll recognize it's basicity on this page

Comment: But back to the question: does solvation increase the size of the proton; if so, is the proton then sterically hindered?

Comment: yes solvation does, it is not correct to comment whether it eould be strecially hindered, but i guess it would be, wait i'm working with 3d models and will tell if i get something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much hinderance[note that they all have been optimised to stable configurations]
Blue: nitrogen,White: Hydrogen,Grey: Carbon

### Side View:

[image]

### Top View:

[image]

Comment: The methyls on the left seem eclipsed in the top pic, is that the most stable conformed? Also can another Lewis acid get to the lone pair on nitrogen? I.e would say a metal cation be too big to fit?

Comment: @Dissenter I just used optimise geometry function and this is what i got.

Comment: Cool. What program?

Comment: @Dissenter avogardo